# public function that loads image async and returns UIImage

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uiimage, load

I am trying to write public function that loads image async and returns UIImage. I want to use it in filling UITableView with images.

```
class CommonFunctions {

func loadImageAsync(StringURL: NSString) -> UIImage{

    var returningImage = UIImage()

    let url = NSURL(string: StringURL)

    let requestedURL = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestedURL, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("there is some error loading image")
        }
        else {

            if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                returningImage = image
            }
        }
    })
    return returningImage
    }

}
```

the problem is that when I want to use this function :

```
cell.imageModelImage.image = CommonFunctions.loadImageAsync(CommonFunctions)
```

Instead of String argument I get the class? Why is that so?

Comment: Why do you pass CommonFunctions as parameter to loadImageAsyn()? And why do you call instance method as class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> Instead of String argument I get the class? Why is that so?

It is because you are calling it as if it was a class function, but didn't define it as such. If you add the `class` keyword on the declaration of the function, you won't see that behavior.

But there are deeper issues here: You cannot return a value from an asynchronous function (because the function will return immediately while the asynchronous request will not complete until later).

One solution is to provide a completion handler that will be called if the image is retrieved successfully:

```
class func loadImageAsync(stringURL: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: stringURL)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(nil, error) }
            return
        }
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(image, nil) }
    }.resume()
}
```

Note, I'm dispatching the completion handler back to the main queue, where all UI updates should take place.

Then, in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, you can supply a block that will be called when the asynchronous request is done:

```
cell.imageModelImage.image = ... // remember to initialize image view before starting async method
CommonFunctions.loadImageAsync(with: "http://example.com/test.jpg") { image, error in
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {  // make sure cell hasn't scrolled out of view
        cell.imageModelImage.image = image
    }
}
```

Note, the above assumes that it's impossible to insert a row in the table in the intervening period of time. If that assumption is not valid, rather than using the old `indexPath`, you might have requery your model to identify what `IndexPath` is valid for this cell when the asynchronous completion handler is called.

For Swift 2 rendition, see the [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29469903/2) of this answer.

Comment: Which method would be the preferred method for Swift?